# how to prepare gray image data for caffe input

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have read lots of references to prepare image data for caffe input but have not been able to solve my problem yet!!

I have put `.jpg` image files in 2 seperate folders:

```
folder  train: containing 100,000 image files of size 227*227
folder val: containing 9,000 image files of size 227*227
```

I put them in a folder in `/home/user/DL`

Then I made two text files listing the names of the images in `train` and `val` folders as:

```
.
.
p127.jpg 2
p943.jpg 2
p8765.jpg 1
.
.
```

and I put these two files in `/home/user/caffe-master/data/DL`.

I made `DL_create.sh` located in `/home/user/caffe-master/examples/DL` as bellow:

```
set -e

EXAMPLE=examples/DL
DATA=data/DL
TOOLS=build/tools

TRAIN_DATA_ROOT=/home/user/DL/train/
VAL_DATA_ROOT=/home/user/DL/val/


RESIZE=true
if $RESIZE; then
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=227
  RESIZE_WIDTH=227
else
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=0
  RESIZE_WIDTH=0
fi

if [ ! -d "$TRAIN_DATA_ROOT" ]; then
  echo "Error: TRAIN_DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory:  $TRAIN_DATA_ROOT"
  echo "Set the TRAIN_DATA_ROOT variable in create_DL.sh to  the path" \
       "where the DL training data is stored."
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$VAL_DATA_ROOT" ]; then
  echo "Error: VAL_DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory: $VAL_DATA_ROOT"
  echo "Set the VAL_DATA_ROOT variable in create_DL.sh to the path" \
       "where the DL validation data is stored."
  exit 1
fi

echo "Creating train lmdb..."

GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \
    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
    --shuffle \
    --gray \
    $TRAIN_DATA_ROOT \
    $DATA/train.txt \
    $EXAMPLE/DL_train_lmdb

echo "Creating val lmdb..."

GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \
    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
    --shuffle \
    --gray \
    $VAL_DATA_ROOT \
    $DATA/val.txt \
    $EXAMPLE/DL_val_lmdb

echo "Done."
```

Then when I run `DL_create.sh` script to change my image data into `lmdb` it can not find my images and gives messages like:

```
.
.
.
E0922 14:35:24.152361 31301 io.cpp:80] Could not open or find file /home/user/caffe-master/data/DL/train/p84167.jpg
E0922 14:35:24.160773 31301 io.cpp:80] Could not open or find file /home/user/caffe-master/data/DL/train/p24118.jpg
.
.
.
```

could you please help me know where I am doing mistake??!?!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the images I had were uint16 bitmap!! However, after lots of search I found that caffe works on uint8 bitmap

Comment: If this was your solution you should consider accepting your answer. Also : You can define a scale for the images itself in the input layer